# c# Encryption in a multi-layered Streams read/write

Tags: c#, encryption, stream, aes, padding

There are files created from multiple layers of data:

```
    //input is not always the same, but the structure is, so for example there might be h4 and h5, but I will know that, so that is not the problem
    private void generalizationofwrittendata(string filename, int someint, int chunks, string outputfilename, ICryptoTransform crypt, byte[] somedata, int h1, int h2, int h3)
    {
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(outputfilename, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
        {
            using (BinaryWriter w = new BinaryWriter(fs, Encoding.ASCII))
            {
                //writing some data with binary writer
                w.Write(h1);
                w.Write(h2);
                w.Write(h3);
                using (FileStream fsIn = File.OpenRead(filename))
                {
                    using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(fs, crypt, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                    {
                        //writing the rest of data with crypto stream
                        cs.Write(somedata, 0, somedata.Length);
                        byte[] chunk = new byte[chunks];
                        int bytesRead = 0;
                        while ((bytesRead = fsIn.Read(chunk, 0, chunks)) > 0)
                        {
                            cs.Write(chunk, 0, bytesRead);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

"generalizationofwrittendata" works perfectly fine in an intended way.

Now the problem is in separating all of that data from the file:

```
private void test(string filename, int someint, int chunks, string outputfilename, ICryptoTransform crypt)
    {
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs, Encoding.ASCII))
            {
                //reading some not encrypted data
                int h1 = br.ReadInt32();
                int h2 = br.ReadInt32();
                int h3 = br.ReadInt32();
                using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(fs, crypt, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                {
                    using (BinaryReader br2 = new BinaryReader(cs, Encoding.ASCII))
                    {
                        //reading some encrypted data
                        byte[] somedata = br2.ReadBytes(someint);
                        //writing the rest of the data to file
                        using (FileStream fsOut = new FileStream(outputfilename, FileMode.Create))
                        {
                            byte[] chunk = new byte[chunks];
                            int bytesRead = 0;
                            while ((bytesRead = cs.Read(chunk, 0, chunks)) > 0)
                            {
                                fsOut.Write(chunk, 0, bytesRead);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This approach simply doesn't work. Only h1,h2,h3 can be received back in this way. somedata will be different and the written file will be longer than the original data, which lead me to thinking that the problem is with CryptoStream+BinaryReader reading from the beginning of the file.
Probably you will suggest me to use `MemoryStream`, but this will be valid only for small files, thus will lead to memory out of range exception.
The only other solution I found was [SubStream](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/c409b63b-37df-40ca-9322-458ffe06ea48/how-to-access-part-of-a-filestream-or-memorystream?forum=netfxbcl) implementation, but unfortunately when I used it between "fs" and "cs" it resulted in wrong "somedata" and the resulted file had wrong data as well.

Maybe there is a way to do this using [Memory-Mapped Files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/memory-mapped-files)? But I'm not quite sure how would I need to approach it in that way.
Or maybe I'm missing something else, since writing in "generalizationofwrittendata" using BinaryWriter and then CryptoStream does seem to work just fine.

Update#1:

So after receiving replies I've rechecked all of the code, especially related to ICryptoTransform. The ICryptoTransform is definitely not the problem, it is exactly the same for both methods.

The other thing that I noticed was that I used "BinaryReader br2" for no apparent reason, so I have removed that:

```
private void test(string filename, int someint, int chunks, string outputfilename, ICryptoTransform crypt)
    {
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs, Encoding.ASCII))
            {
                //reading some not encrypted data
                int h1 = br.ReadInt32();
                int h2 = br.ReadInt32();
                int h3 = br.ReadInt32();
                using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(fs, crypt, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                {
                    //reading some encrypted data
                    byte[] somedata = new byte[someint];
                    cs.Read(somedata, 0, someint);
                    //writing the rest of the data to file
                    using (FileStream fsOut = new FileStream(outputfilename, FileMode.Create))
                    {
                        byte[] chunk = new byte[chunks];
                        int bytesRead = 0;
                        while ((bytesRead = cs.Read(chunk, 0, chunks)) > 0)
                        {
                            fsOut.Write(chunk, 0, bytesRead);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

But unfortunately that hasn't solved the issue, both somedata and the data written to file aren't the same as original.

Update#2:

So that was a stupid problem - I've created `CreateEncryptor()` instead of `CreateDecryptor()` for decryption.

Comment: The *someint* variable is dangerous, guessing at its value wrong produces garbage.  There just isn't point at guessing at it, just write somedata.Length to the file like you do with h1...h3 so the reader always knows the correct value.

Comment: For the sake of simple example I have oversimplified things (the amount of real code is x10 the size, due to how data is generated), just think about input being always the same for both functions, including someint.

Comment: Doh! It really wasn't the code you posted then ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly I am being thick, but couldn't you just seek to the appropriate position of fs and continue to use the same binary reader?

I will try this but setting up a crypto key will take some time.

Edit: Also, are you certain that you are building the CryptoTransform correctly when you decrypt?

Edit:
Your code works as you supplied it when I use the following code:

```
    byte[] testdata = new byte[] { 0x12, 0x34, 0x56 };
    byte[] key;
    byte[] iv;

    String encryptedFile = "encrypted.bin";
    private void buttonCrypt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ICryptoTransform transform;
        RijndaelManaged rjndl = new RijndaelManaged();
        rjndl.KeySize = 256;
        rjndl.BlockSize = 256;
        rjndl.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
        transform = rjndl.CreateEncryptor();
        key = (byte[])rjndl.Key.Clone();
        iv = (byte[])rjndl.IV.Clone();
        generalizationofwrittendata("plain.bin",testdata.Length,1,encryptedFile,transform,testdata,0x0abbccdd,0x01223344,0x09887766);
    }

    private void buttonDecrypt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RijndaelManaged rjndl = new RijndaelManaged();
        rjndl.KeySize = 256;
        rjndl.BlockSize = 256;
        rjndl.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
        var transform = rjndl.CreateDecryptor(key, iv);
        test(encryptedFile, testdata.Length, 1, "decrypted.bin", transform);
    }
```

The other data is read as {0x12,0x34,0x56}, h1 to h3 are the values I supplied and decrypted.bin is the same as plain.bin.

This points to a problem with the key you are supplying to the decryptor.

Update 1:

I have modded my test harness to use Aes:

```
    private void buttonCrypt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ICryptoTransform transform;
        AesManaged Aes = new AesManaged();
        Aes.KeySize = 256;
        Aes.BlockSize = 128;
        Aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
        Aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
        transform = Aes.CreateEncryptor();
        key = (byte[])Aes.Key.Clone();
        iv = (byte[])Aes.IV.Clone();
        generalizationofwrittendata("plain.bin",testdata.Length,1,encryptedFile,transform,testdata,0x0abbccdd,0x01223344,0x09887766);
    }

    private void buttonDecrypt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AesManaged Aes = new AesManaged();
        Aes.KeySize = 256;
        Aes.BlockSize = 128;
        Aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
        Aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
        var transform = Aes.CreateDecryptor(key, iv);
        test(encryptedFile, testdata.Length, 1, "decrypted.bin", transform);
    }
```

The results are identical, it still works as you originally posted it.

I am getting Aes to create a key and initialisation vector which I save, you need to check that the encryption and decryption both call your Aes generator with **exactly** the same values. Also, ensure that you are using Aes.CreateEncyptor() to encrypt and Aes.CreateDecryptor() to decrypt.

The problem really does have to be in the keys so my suggestion is to break after you create the encryptor and dump the key/iv, then do the same after you create the decryptor and check that they are byte for byte identical.

Comment: No idea how would I use the same binaryreader, since only one of them should read through cryptostream. Used CryptoTransform is the same for both functions. Key is definitely not the issue, but if it works for you then maybe it has something to do with the size of data, I'll try to generate some small-sized unrelated data for tests and will update the question or this comment after that, thanks.

Comment: I can only say that creating a simple key as above and feeding it to your methods does exactly what you wanted it to do, so there is nothing wrong with your methodology. That really only  leaves the key, unless someone else has a reason that I can't spot :-)

Comment: I take your point about needing a new binary reader - it is on a different stream. Duh. I think what I was intendeding to say was that if you were in doubt about the position of fs you could issue a seek and then create the cryptostream, I got it around my neck.

Comment: I just noticed that you said you used the same transform... you can't; one of them is an encrypter and the other is a decrypter.