# C# encrypts successfully, won't decrypt

Tags: c#, encryption

I'll try to keep this as brief as possible.

Please be nice, I don't generally write C#, and neither does the developer who initially wrote this class.

Anyway simple enough concept, call the EncryptString static method with the string and the key. Then call DecryptString with the encrypted string and the key (same as before).

This is used to output a file which is saved on the filesystem, and then get the contents (via another class).

The problem I'm having is that encryption is working perfectly well, but on decryption I get an exception about the key. Been scratching my head for a couple of hours on this now, after the other developer also scratching his head for a couple of hours.

**Class Responsible:**

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;

namespace MySoftwarePackage.Pakages
{
    public class Encrypt
    {

        public static string DecryptString(string cipherText, string encryptionKey)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("ENCRYPTION KEY: " + encryptionKey);

            var fullCipher = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);

            var iv = new byte[16];
            var cipher = new byte[32];

            Buffer.BlockCopy(fullCipher, 0, iv, 0, iv.Length);
            Buffer.BlockCopy(fullCipher, iv.Length, cipher, 0, iv.Length);
            var key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(encryptionKey);

            Console.WriteLine("ENCODED: " + key);

            using (var aesAlg = Aes.Create())
            {
                using (var decryptor = aesAlg.CreateDecryptor(key, iv))
                {
                    string result;
                    using (var msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(cipher))
                    {
                        using (var csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                        {
                            using (var srDecrypt = new StreamReader(csDecrypt))
                            {
                                result = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    return result;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Exceptions:**

```
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[13]
      Connection id "0HL83721K735O": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Specified padding mode is not valid for this algorithm.
   at Internal.Cryptography.UniversalCryptoDecryptor.DepadBlock(Byte[] block, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at Internal.Cryptography.UniversalCryptoDecryptor.UncheckedTransformFinalBlock(Byte[] inputBuffer, Int32 inputOffset, Int32 inputCount)
   at Internal.Cryptography.UniversalCryptoTransform.TransformFinalBlock(Byte[] inputBuffer, Int32 inputOffset, Int32 inputCount)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock()
   at System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStream.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at System.IO.Stream.Close()
   at System.IO.StreamReader.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at System.IO.TextReader.Dispose()
   at MySoftwarePackage.Pakages.Encrypt.DecryptString(String cipherText, String encryptionKey) in /Users/matt/SoftwarePackage-desktop/src/api/Pakages/Encrypt.cs:line 39
   at MySoftwarePackage.Pakages.DataRetriever.UnencryptData() in /Users/matt/SoftwarePackage-desktop/src/api/Pakages/DataRetriever.cs:line 39
   at MySoftwarePackage.Pakages.DataRetriever..ctor(String entityType, String entityId) in /Users/matt/SoftwarePackage-desktop/src/api/Pakages/DataRetriever.cs:line 24
   at MySoftwarePackage.Controllers.BusinessController.TestGet() in /Users/matt/SoftwarePackage-desktop/src/api/Controllers/BusinessController.cs:line 292
   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>d__27.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>d__25.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>d__22.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeAsync>d__20.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.<Invoke>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.RequestServicesContainerMiddleware.<Invoke>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Http.Frame`1.<RequestProcessingAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
```

Comment: Apologies I forgot to mention, we're using .NET core so we can't use Rijndael - which looks like it would be a lot easier!

Comment: The error is right there: _Specified padding mode is not valid for this algorithm._

Comment: Also, don't use Encoding.GetBytes() to turn a password into a key. Look up PasswordDeriveBytes

Comment: Yeah I get that, but I don't know how to change it - and it's not a password we just need to encrypt the contents of a file so that we can get it later. We're not C# developers by any means, but we've inherited this piece of code which we need to make work, hence the newby questions

Comment: If you post the encryptor as well as the decryptor I could put it in a test harness and stop speculating. [The last one I had was a simple fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46385343/c-sharp-encryption-in-a-multi-layered-streams-read-write/46388350#46388350)

Answer (score 2):

Rijndael/AES is a block cypher.

It encrypts data in 128 bit (16 character) blocks. Cryptographic padding is used to make sure that last block of the message is always the correct size.

You need to explicitly set the padding for both encryption and decryption by setting PaddingMode

Try setting PaddingMode to `PaddingMode.PKCS7`

Also, make your key to be of 16 characters blocks (16, 32, etc.)

Comment: We can't use Rijndael, annoyingly.

Thanks for your message though I'll see if I can set the PaddingMode or if that gives me a good enough clue to fix the issue

Comment: you are using AES, which also have the same requirement as Rijndael

Comment: Ah okay, fair enough.
So how would I set the Padding Mode?

Comment: So I've set the padding mode like so: `aesAlg.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;` but still no joy, I'm getting the same error. Which is odd as I've set it the same on the encrypt method and it's running fine.

Comment: is your key of 16 characters blocks?

Comment: Yeah it is, it's weird as it works fine on encryption - no errors or anything - it only breaks on decryption which is what is so confusing

Comment: did you set your padding mode on both encryption and decryption method?

Comment: Alright, I am giving you some sample codes examples: https://gist.github.com/mark-adams/87aa34da3a5ed48ed0c7

Answer (score 0):

I think the line

```
     Buffer.BlockCopy(fullCipher, iv.Length, cipher, 0, iv.Length);
```

should actually be

```
     Buffer.BlockCopy(fullCipher, iv.Length, cipher, 0, cipher.Length);
```

You aren't setting all of cipher.

Edit to please the pedant:

This assumes that you created your encryption key by extracting the first 16 bytes to use as the initialisation vector and the next 32 to use as your key.

If you symmetrically used 16 in both cases then I haven't got a clue why it isn't working.

Comment: I don't know that 32 bytes is really the intent. But definitely the notion of "you are reading 16 bytes instead of 'the rest'" holds. Probably easier to put the whole IV and ciphertext into the MemoryStream and seek it forward by the IV size.

Comment: fullcipher is 48 bytes (at least), the first iv.Length (16) are iv, the remaining are the key so it has to be 32. Copying iv.Length will leave 16 bytes of cipher set to zero. The key for AES is 32 bytes.

Comment: I will also add that it is always best practise to set the full key and iv in all cases, it means you don't get subtle errors - rather like this one. What would be the cryptographic sense in throwing 50% of the keyspace if 16 (or less than 32) was intended?

Comment: Since fullCipher is the result of a base64 decode and we don't know the input, the `cipher` portion could be any length up to 1.5Gb (since the string would be capped at 2.4 billion length)

Answer (score 0):

Since it seems you are attempting to encrypt/decrypt in AES you should probably look for an existing library in the Nuget repository (nuget.org). There are plenty of them.

Just to name a couple of popular ones:

**SimpleAesEncryption** https://github.com/ArtisanCode/SimpleAesEncryption

**csharp-aes** https://gitlab.com/czubehead/csharp-aes

There are examples of usage for each in their README files.

Answer (score -1):

Just ran into the same problem, with identical code, gratefully borrowed from http://mikaelkoskinen.net/post/encrypt-decrypt-string-asp-net-core. I found that this would throw the exception noted above if the original cleartext was more than 16 characters (bytes?).  Anyway, the fix is:
This line:

`var cipher = new byte[32];`

should be:

`var cipher = new byte[fullCipher.Length - iv.Length];`

Then, this line:

`Buffer.BlockCopy(fullCipher, iv.Length, cipher, 0, iv.Length);`

should be:

`Buffer.BlockCopy(fullCipher, iv.Length, cipher, 0, cipher.Length);`

as noted by Kevin previously.